# Removing and reassigning ClickHandler back

Tags: java, gwt

I need to remove `ClickHandler` from a UI widget and later reassign it back. First I create `ClickHandler` and assign it to widget. Then when I need to remove handler,  check if there is some existing `HandlerRegistration` already, if there it is, I remove it. Later I do the opposite - I check if the `HandlerRegistration` is null (because I don't wanna have two same handlers on one widget), if it is, I assign it.

```
private HandlerRegistration handlerReg;
private ClickHandler handler;
handler = new ClickHandler() {
        
        @Override
        public void onClick(ClickEvent arg0) {
        // do stuff
        }
}
handlerReg = widget.addClickHandler(handler);

// some code later:
if (handlerReg != null){
    handlerReg.removeHandler();
    handlerReg = null;
}

// some other code later:
if (handlerReg == null) {
    handlerReg = widget.addClickHandler(handler);                           
}
```

Even if I try not to, this approach results in having multiple handlers binded to one widget. How can I do that correctly?

Comment: This looks OK to me.

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks OK at first glance. You can also try a simpler solution: to temporarily *suspend* handler execution with a variable, let's say `handlerEnabled`, for example:

```
@Override
public void onClick(ClickEvent arg0) {
    if(handlerEnabled) {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

Then you wouldn't have to juggle with `HandlerRegistration`.